# Call sub in other form using c#

Tags: c#, .net

i Have a short problem.

How could i call this sub

```
private void test()
{
   panel1.visible = false;
   panel2.visible = false;
}
```

into other form?

I tried like this

`private static void`

and the problem is that i cannot add/include the panel control inside in my sub. I already change the modifiers of my control into `public`

what should i do so that i can execute that sort of code in other form.

Comment: change private to public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your form which contains your test method is open. You can do this (as your **first** option):

```
//Replace Form1 as the name of your form
Form1 frm = (Form1)Application.OpenForms[0]; //If there are only two forms, 0 index will work fine
frm.test();
```

This will execute your test method and will hide the panels.

Make sure your test is in public:

```
public void test()
{...}
```

This is another option:
In your first form where you have you have your test method, pass the form as parameter in constructor:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
frm.Show();
```

On your **second** form where you need to access the test method:

```
  public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Form1 form1;
    public Form2(Form1 form1)
        : this()
    {
        // TODO: If you have other member initialization
        this.form1 = form1;
    }
```

Now you can access the test method and hide your panels:

```
form1.test();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
public void test() {
...
}
```

and then you'll be able to call it like

```
form2.test();
```

Answer (score 0):

You either make the panel static or call it from another form like `form.test();`